# What is the Log API to call from an Android JNI program?

Tags: android, c, android-emulator, android-ndk

I would like to debug a JNI C application by inserting log messages to logcat.  What is the C API that does this?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <android/log.h>


__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "Error here");//Or ANDROID_LOG_INFO, ...
```

Add it to your makefile like this:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
```

Comment: "-L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib" part is not necessary, just "LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog" will work the same.
For those it doesn't work anyway (like me)) - I had line "include $(CLEAR_VARS)" in my Android.mk _after_ "LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog", moved it _before_, and it works OK now.

Comment: Just in case if this doesn't work, see below solution.

Comment: or __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Tag", "i%c works lik%x print%x", 't', 14, 15);

Answer (score 14):

Following is the code snippet that you should include in your native code.

```
#include <android/log.h>


__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "Error msg");//Or ANDROID_LOG_INFO, ...
```

In order to use the above API, we need to link the corresponding library.

We can link a shared library in Android in 3 ways.
In below 3 cases, the lines mentioned should be added in `Android.mk`

So here are the three ways.

```
#1. LOCAL_LDLIBS way
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

For some reason if 1 doesnt work(it did not work for me), You can try below 2 ways

```
#2. LOCAL_LDFLAGS way
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -llog

#3. LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES way
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += liblog
```

Answer (score 11):

**`syslog`**

This POSIX function also outputs to logcat.

It has the advantage of being more portable across non Android systems than `__android_log_write` and it automatically adds the app package to the log.

Tested with this example app: https://github.com/cirosantilli/android-cheat/tree/a080f5c370c1f06e74a8300fb4a2e93369861047/gradle/NdkSyslog the NDK source is:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <syslog.h>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_cirosantilli_android_1cheat_ndksyslog_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "hello syslog");
    return env->NewStringUTF("Check adb logcat");
}
```

And logcat now contains:

```
01-14 15:39:07.582  3633  3633 E com.cirosantilli.android_cheat.ndksyslog: hello syslog
```

Tested on Android O, HiKey 960.

Comment: it only supports literals