# Is possible to print C-code console output through JNI in an android application?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk, native-code

I read this [post](http://integratingstuff.com/2010/12/12/calling-native-c-code-through-jni-in-android-applications/) on how calling native c-code through JNI in Android applications.
I have tested the code and works fine! This program makes a JNI call and prints a string
that comes from a C function. Is possible to show the console output of a C function
(e.g. the results of printf etc.) in an Android app with the same way?

http://integratingstuff.com/2010/12/12/calling-native-c-code-through-jni-in-android-applications/

Comment: "prompt the console output of a C function"?  What does that mean?

Comment: I mean the output of the printfs it contains..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of printf to console you print to logcat using the function __android_log_write(...). More details about how to set this up here: [What is the Log API to call from an Android JNI program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465941/what-is-the-log-api-to-call-from-an-android-jni-program/5466040#5466040)

Comment: Ok! It seems to be a good idea! Thank you! Is it possible to redirect this output to an Android Interface component like a textview for example so as to be shown from the application?

Comment: I'm not sure Thanasis, sorry.

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas: did you figure out a way to print them to android screen? Kindly let me know