# How to print log in android c++ file?

Tags: android, logging

I added

```
#define LOG_NDEBUG 0
#define LOG_TAG "StagefrightMediaScanner"
#include <utils/Log.h>
```

in the `libstagefright/StagefrightMediaScanner.cpp`

but can not print anything using LOGV and LOGE, does any other things can I need to do?

Comment: @Lucifer No, I am using android 4.0 source code to debug the framework's issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Log API to call from an Android JNI program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465941/what-is-the-log-api-to-call-from-an-android-jni-program)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the following code to  get Log

```
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS", "%s", Str);
```

and add the following header file

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

Additional docs are here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging

Comment: what is Str in this case? Is it a variable, what will be its value

Comment: __android_log_write()

Comment: Also need to modify Android.mk, add "LOCAL_LDLIBS :=-llog"

Answer (score 2):

You can check frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/Android.mk,
whether there is

```
 LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += liblog
```

in it.

Then, under `frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/`

```
$ mm

$ adb push $OUT/system/lib/libstagefright.so /system/lib/ 

$ adb shell killall mediaserver
```

Then reboot your phone or am start a `MEDIA_MOUNTED` intent, MediaScanner will work, and the logs you just added(either `ALOGE/ALOGV` or `LOGE/LOGV`) should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

No you have done right. Just check it whether you are using ALOGV() which is similar to printf(),if you want to print a integer with a log then you can write like this :" ALOGV("Integer is %d",integer);".

Answer (score 0):

---

TestLog.cpp

```
{

#define LOG_VERBOSE(message, ...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "MY_LOG_TAG", "[%s %s] " message, __FILE_NAME__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__))


    void logFunction1() {
        char *testStatus = "Success";
        LOG_VERBOSE("This is my log, Status : %s", testStatus);
        logFunction2();
    }
    
    void logFunction2() {
        LOG_VERBOSE("Hope this is helpful !");
    }
}
```

---

output :

> V  [TestLog.cpp logFunction1] This is my log, Status : Success
>
> V  [TestLog.cpp logFunction2] Hope this is helpful !

---